# Wildfly 12 & 13 duplicate standalone.xml file and log it as an infinite loop

Tags: java, wildfly

I'm experiencing something curious with Wildfly 13 today and I didn't experience it yesterday (first time I installed and used it).  When I launch the server, everything seems OK and Wildfly loads and launches my custom standalone.xml file :

```
2018-06-27 14:32:35,560 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "remmedia-standalone.xml" (runtime-name: "remmedia-standalone.xml")
```

But then, it loads and logs all other versions of standalone xml files it founds into the configuration folder :

```
2018-06-27 14:32:35,561 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "standalone-full-ha.xml" (runtime-name: "standalone-full-ha.xml")
2018-06-27 14:32:35,561 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "standalone-ha.xml" (runtime-name: "standalone-ha.xml")
2018-06-27 14:32:35,561 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "standalone-full.xml" (runtime-name: "standalone-full.xml")
2018-06-27 14:32:35,560 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "standalone-load-balancer.xml" (runtime-name: "standalone-load-balancer.xml")
2018-06-27 14:32:35,561 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "remmedia-standalone.v1.xml" (runtime-name: "remmedia-standalone.v1.xml")
2018-06-27 14:32:35,560 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "standalone-ee8.xml" (runtime-name: "standalone-ee8.xml")
2018-06-27 14:32:35,561 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "standalone.xml" (runtime-name: "standalone.xml")
```

And then the carrousel seems to restart as an infinite loop, even by versioning my remmedia-standalone.xml file into the standalone-xml-history subfolder.

```
2018-06-27 14:32:35,564 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "remmedia-standalone.initial.xml" (runtime-name: "remmedia-standalone.initial.xml")
2018-06-27 14:32:35,564 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "remmedia-standalone.boot.xml" (runtime-name: "remmedia-standalone.boot.xml")
2018-06-27 14:32:35,565 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "remmedia-standalone.last.xml" (runtime-name: "remmedia-standalone.last.xml")
2018-06-27 14:32:37,214 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-2) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Gaina' 9.2.4.Final
2018-06-27 14:32:37,698 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) WFLYCLINF0002: Started client-mappings cache from ejb container
2018-06-27 14:32:37,933 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "remmedia-standalone.last.xml" (runtime-name : "remmedia-standalone.last.xml")
2018-06-27 14:32:37,933 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "remmedia-standalone.initial.xml" (runtime-name : "remmedia-standalone.initial.xml")
2018-06-27 14:32:37,933 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "remmedia-standalone.boot.xml" (runtime-name : "remmedia-standalone.boot.xml")
2018-06-27 14:32:37,933 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "remmedia-standalone.v1.xml" (runtime-name : "remmedia-standalone.v1.xml")
2018-06-27 14:32:37,934 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "standalone.xml" (runtime-name : "standalone.xml")
2018-06-27 14:32:37,934 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "standalone-load-balancer.xml" (runtime-name : "standalone-load-balancer.xml")
2018-06-27 14:32:37,934 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "standalone-ha.xml" (runtime-name : "standalone-ha.xml")
2018-06-27 14:32:37,934 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "standalone-full.xml" (runtime-name : "standalone-full.xml")
2018-06-27 14:32:37,934 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "standalone-full-ha.xml" (runtime-name : "standalone-full-ha.xml")
2018-06-27 14:32:37,934 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "standalone-ee8.xml" (runtime-name : "standalone-ee8.xml")
2018-06-27 14:32:37,934 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "remmedia-standalone.xml" (runtime-name : "remmedia-standalone.xml")
2018-06-27 14:32:43,076 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment remmedia-standalone.xml (runtime-name: remmedia-standalone.xml) in 35ms
2018-06-27 14:32:43,081 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "remmedia-standalone.xml" (runtime-name: "remmedia-standalone.xml")
2018-06-27 14:32:43,082 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "remmedia-standalone.v2.xml" (runtime-name: "remmedia-standalone.v2.xml")
2018-06-27 14:32:43,091 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment remmedia-standalone.last.xml (runtime-name: remmedia-standalone.last.xml) in 8ms
2018-06-27 14:32:43,092 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "remmedia-standalone.last.xml" (runtime-name: "remmedia-standalone.last.xml")
2018-06-27 14:32:43,135 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYSRV0016: Replaced deployment "remmedia-standalone.last.xml" with deployment "remmedia-standalone.last.xml"
2018-06-27 14:32:43,136 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "remmedia-standalone.v2.xml" (runtime-name : "remmedia-standalone.v2.xml")
2018-06-27 14:32:43,136 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYSRV0016: Replaced deployment "remmedia-standalone.xml" with deployment "remmedia-standalone.xml"
2018-06-27 14:32:48,202 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment remmedia-standalone.xml (runtime-name: remmedia-standalone.xml) in 10ms
2018-06-27 14:32:48,204 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "remmedia-standalone.xml" (runtime-name: "remmedia-standalone.xml")
2018-06-27 14:32:48,207 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "remmedia-standalone.v3.xml" (runtime-name: "remmedia-standalone.v3.xml")
2018-06-27 14:32:48,247 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment remmedia-standalone.last.xml (runtime-name: remmedia-standalone.last.xml) in 43ms
2018-06-27 14:32:48,250 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "remmedia-standalone.last.xml" (runtime-name: "remmedia-standalone.last.xml")
2018-06-27 14:32:48,294 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYSRV0016: Replaced deployment "remmedia-standalone.last.xml" with deployment "remmedia-standalone.last.xml"
2018-06-27 14:32:48,294 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "remmedia-standalone.v3.xml" (runtime-name : "remmedia-standalone.v3.xml")
2018-06-27 14:32:48,295 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYSRV0016: Replaced deployment "remmedia-standalone.xml" with deployment "remmedia-standalone.xml"
2018-06-27 14:32:53,366 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment remmedia-standalone.xml (runtime-name: remmedia-standalone.xml) in 15ms
2018-06-27 14:32:53,369 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "remmedia-standalone.xml" (runtime-name: "remmedia-standalone.xml")
2018-06-27 14:32:53,370 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "remmedia-standalone.v4.xml" (runtime-name: "remmedia-standalone.v4.xml")
2018-06-27 14:32:53,385 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment remmedia-standalone.last.xml (runtime-name: remmedia-standalone.last.xml) in 16ms
2018-06-27 14:32:53,386 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "remmedia-standalone.last.xml" (runtime-name: "remmedia-standalone.last.xml")
2018-06-27 14:32:53,418 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYSRV0016: Replaced deployment "remmedia-standalone.last.xml" with deployment "remmedia-standalone.last.xml"
2018-06-27 14:32:53,418 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "remmedia-standalone.v4.xml" (runtime-name : "remmedia-standalone.v4.xml")
2018-06-27 14:32:53,418 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYSRV0016: Replaced deployment "remmedia-standalone.xml" with deployment "remmedia-standalone.xml"
2018-06-27 14:32:58,569 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment remmedia-standalone.xml (runtime-name: remmedia-standalone.xml) in 6ms
2018-06-27 14:32:58,572 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "remmedia-standalone.xml" (runtime-name: "remmedia-standalone.xml")
2018-06-27 14:32:58,573 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "remmedia-standalone.v5.xml" (runtime-name: "remmedia-standalone.v5.xml")
2018-06-27 14:32:58,615 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment remmedia-standalone.last.xml (runtime-name: remmedia-standalone.last.xml) in 44ms
2018-06-27 14:32:58,620 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "remmedia-standalone.last.xml" (runtime-name: "remmedia-standalone.last.xml")
2018-06-27 14:32:58,698 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYSRV0016: Replaced deployment "remmedia-standalone.last.xml" with deployment "remmedia-standalone.last.xml"
2018-06-27 14:32:58,699 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "remmedia-standalone.v5.xml" (runtime-name : "remmedia-standalone.v5.xml")
2018-06-27 14:32:58,699 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYSRV0016: Replaced deployment "remmedia-standalone.xml" with deployment "remmedia-standalone.xml"
2018-06-27 14:33:03,759 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment remmedia-standalone.xml (runtime-name: remmedia-standalone.xml) in 8ms
2018-06-27 14:33:03,761 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "remmedia-standalone.xml" (runtime-name: "remmedia-standalone.xml")
2018-06-27 14:33:03,763 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "remmedia-standalone.v6.xml" (runtime-name: "remmedia-standalone.v6.xml")
2018-06-27 14:33:03,780 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment remmedia-standalone.last.xml (runtime-name: remmedia-standalone.last.xml) in 20ms
2018-06-27 14:33:03,783 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "remmedia-standalone.last.xml" (runtime-name: "remmedia-standalone.last.xml")
2018-06-27 14:33:03,816 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYSRV0016: Replaced deployment "remmedia-standalone.last.xml" with deployment "remmedia-standalone.last.xml"
2018-06-27 14:33:03,816 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "remmedia-standalone.v6.xml" (runtime-name : "remmedia-standalone.v6.xml")
2018-06-27 14:33:03,816 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYSRV0016: Replaced deployment "remmedia-standalone.xml" with deployment "remmedia-standalone.xml"
2018-06-27 14:33:08,892 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment remmedia-standalone.xml (runtime-name: remmedia-standalone.xml) in 6ms
2018-06-27 14:33:08,899 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "remmedia-standalone.v7.xml" (runtime-name: "remmedia-standalone.v7.xml")
2018-06-27 14:33:08,899 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "remmedia-standalone.xml" (runtime-name: "remmedia-standalone.xml")
2018-06-27 14:33:08,906 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment remmedia-standalone.last.xml (runtime-name: remmedia-standalone.last.xml) in 8ms
2018-06-27 14:33:08,907 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "remmedia-standalone.last.xml" (runtime-name: "remmedia-standalone.last.xml")
2018-06-27 14:33:08,941 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYSRV0016: Replaced deployment "remmedia-standalone.last.xml" with deployment "remmedia-standalone.last.xml"
2018-06-27 14:33:08,941 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "remmedia-standalone.v7.xml" (runtime-name : "remmedia-standalone.v7.xml")
```

This behaviour is new. And I got the same when I tried to launch an instance of Wildfly 12 instead of the Wildfly 13. And I did not experience this yesterday. What's going wrong ? Note that I manage Wildfly instance from Eclipse Oxygen.3a using the JBoss Tools 4.5.3.Final plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer on this link https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-10629

Here's is the excerpt from that thread that helped resolve this problem

> I had the same issue happening to me today. After having a look at the standalone.xml I noticed a second deployment-scanner that was added by jboss-tools:
>
> ```
> <deployment-scanner name="jbosstoolsscanner1" path="C:\dev\appserver\wildfly\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\user_projects\domains\myDomain" scan-interval="5000" deployment-timeout="600"/>
> ```
>
> After removing the scanner that scans the domain directory, wildfly would stop trying to deploy the standalone.xml file. I noticed a setting in the jboss-tools server overview under deployment scanners: There are two checkboxes
>
> 1. Add missing deployment scanners after server startup
> 2. Remove added deployment scanners before shutdown
>
> After unchecking these no second deployment-scanner was added to my standalone.xml file anymore.

Answer (score -1):

OK, finally I solved the issue. Wildfly is not in cause but JBoss Tools plugin.

To fix the issue, I made the following changes on the overview page of the server, as I used to set for older versions of Wildfly :

- Uncheck "Expose your management port as the server's hostname
- Server state Detectors : startup poller = management service
- Server state Detectors : Shutdown Poller = Process Terminated

Comment: please remove the other answer

Comment: I have the same issue now with eclipse IDE.  " the overview page of the server," - do you mean from the jboss admin portal, or something to change in the IDE?  THanks!

Comment: Actually I uninstalled the wildfly 13 execution environment then I did the same with JBoss Tools and I reinstalled JBoss Tools. Every became fine after.